# Fail to use d2i_SSL_SESSION to unserialise SSL_SESSION

Tags: openssl

I want to reuse SSL_SESSION, so I use i2d_SSL_SESSION() to serialise it, and d2i_SSL_SESSION to unserialise. But the d2i_SSL_SESSION failed, the test code is very simple:

after the ssl handshake finished

```
    SSL_SESSION *session = SSL_get1_session(ssl);

    int len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, NULL);
    unsigned char *pp = new unsigned char[len];
    len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, &pp);

    SSL_SESSION *s_new = d2i_SSL_SESSION(NULL, (const unsigned char **)&pp, len);
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    cout << "s_new = " << s_new << endl;
```

the i2d_SSL_SESSION is ok, and the len = 2205

but d2i_SSL_SESSION failed, the s_new is NULL, the error message is:
3078067960:error:0D06703D:asn1 encoding routines:a2i_ASN1_STRING:expecting an asn1 sequence:ssl_asn1.c:370:address=3219682277 offset=0

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i2d_SSL_SESSION` increments the pointer pointed to by `pp` to point one byte after the saved data (unfortunately, the man page isn't very clear on this point).

Try instead:

```
int len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, NULL);
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[len];
unsigned char *p = buffer;
const unsigned char *cp = buffer;
len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, &p);

SSL_SESSION *s_new = d2i_SSL_SESSION(NULL, &cp, len);
```

Note that `d2i_SSL_SESSION()` increments the passed pointer in the same way.  The `d2i_X509()` man page is the best documentation on the general behaviour of all the `d2i_*()` and `i2d_*()` functions in OpenSSL.

Comment: Thank you for this. It is  unfortunate on OpenSSL part to not clearly document it and I spent time debugging it.